# Dart language trignometric functions

Tags: dart

I am creating a scientific calc app in DART . i dont knw how to use trignometric functions like sine , cosine . i used "math.sin()" , but it throws an exception "NO top-level getter math.get declared " how to solve it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please show sample code of how you are calling `Math.sin`.

Answer (score 9):

To use trigonometric functions in Dart, import the `dart:math` library. For example:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  print(sin(pi));
}
```

If you want, you can import with a prefix to avoid namespace collisions:

```dart
import 'dart:math' as Math;

main() {
  print(Math.sin(Math.pi));
}
```